# How do I undo maximize in tig?

Tags: tig

In [tig](http://jonas.nitro.dk/tig/manual.html), I start in the main view, and when I hit `Enter` on a commit, I get a split-screen with the diff view.

I'm scrolling through the diff view, and then I accidentally type `O`. Now the diff view is maximized. I did not want this, and want to go back to what I was looking at before.

How do I un-maximize it so I have my original split screen again?

Comment: Funny, I had exact opposite question, how can I maximize ! got the answer here

Answer (score 5):

There is no un-maximize action provided by Tig. You have to close the diff view (e.g. with `q`) to go back to the main view and then hit `Enter` again.

Comment: Oh, that's a pity, would be great to inspect diff in maximized mode and then get back to normal split view again...