# Shortcut for making tig showing all the branches

Tags: git, tig

There is `tig --all` but I want to be able to switch between usual `tig` and `tig --all` interactively. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Switch to refs view (`r` or `:view-refs`) then select ‘All references’ or a branch.

Comment: tig --all shows all the references as the only view in the terminal.  If I use `r` then `All references`, it shows it to me in a split view.  How can I get the full-terminal view?

Comment: @NedBatchelder: Capital `O` maximizes the current view; at the moment there's [no way to undo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848595/how-do-i-undo-maximize-in-tig) this. (Press `h` to see some more key bindings.)